# Null Percentage Calculation in Google Earth Engine Image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to find the percentage of null values in an image in Google Earth Engine for Sentinel-2 data after cloud masking, i.e., the percentage of an image that has been reduced due to cloud masking. I need the information to know which image is needed for the analysis I am doing or not. The code that I have been writing is:

```
null_pixel_image = sentinel_masked_image.clip(AOI).select('BI')

null_pixel_count = null_pixel_image.eq(0).reduceRegion(
reducer=ee.Reducer.count(),
geometry=null_pixel_image.geometry(),
scale=10,
maxPixels=1e19
)

null_pixel_count = null_pixel_count.getInfo()
```

Now, this gives me the total number of pixels having non-null values but I want to know the percentage of pixels having null values. Any idea on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach won't work as it was written in your question because parameters of **reduceRegion** method are wrong. You can do this determination of percentages by using a procedure similar to your approach with unmasked images (as is in your case) or with masked images (recommended).

So, I artificially produced a masked image by using a DEM where I named it as in your case: **null_pixel_image**. With this masked image, you can use 'pixelArea' method from **ee.Image** objects. The reducer to be used can be count or sum because the ratio between areas (null/total area) is practically the same than between pixel numbers (null/total pixels). However, here it was used count.

Following code determines percentage of null pixels in corresponding **null_pixel_image** as difference from previously calculated non null pixels.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-104.83345718097416, 33.728603299717065],
          [-104.83345718097416, 33.17863231425871],
          [-104.05342788409916, 33.17863231425871],
          [-104.05342788409916, 33.728603299717065]]], null, false);

Map.setOptions("SATELLITE");

var dem = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');

var null_pixel_image = dem.gt(1100).clip(geometry);

null_pixel_image = null_pixel_image.mask(null_pixel_image.eq(1));

Map.centerObject(geometry, 9);
Map.addLayer(null_pixel_image);

var total_pixels = ee.Image.pixelArea().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), 
  geometry: geometry,
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:1e19
}).get("area");

print("total_pixels", total_pixels);

var non_null_pixels = ee.Image.pixelArea().mask(null_pixel_image.eq(1)).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(), 
  geometry:null_pixel_image.geometry(),
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:1e19
}).get("area");

print("non_null_pixels", non_null_pixels);

var non_null_perc = ee.Number(non_null_pixels).divide(ee.Number(total_pixels)).multiply(100);

print("null_perc", ee.Number(100).subtract(non_null_perc));
```

After running [above lines](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b043c69bba91ef4871137e984ab996b8) in GEE code editor, I got following result. Percentage occupied by null pixels (masked in following picture) is about 20 % of total area.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to ask what is var null_pixel_image = dem.gt(1100).clip(geometry);? I am really new to Google Earth Engine so I am confused with that. Can you also please explain the difference between masked image and unmasked image as need in the explanation above. Thank You.

Comment: You don't provide your null_pixel_image so, I artificially produced one; as it can be observed in above picture. Non null pixels have white color and null pixels are masked (you cannot visualized them inside geometry area).